# apply stylesheets based on clicked div element

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm developing an application with Ionic2 and I have 2 stylesheets, **theme1.css** and **theme2.css**.

This is what I want: I have 2 divs. If I click on the first div I will apply theme1.css to all pages of my app while if I click the second div all the pages will use theme2.css .

This is **myPage.html**

```
<div id="theme1" (click)="setTheme('theme1.css')">Apply Theme 1</div>
<div id="theme2" (click)="setTheme('theme2.css')">Apply Theme 2</div>
```

in **myPage.ts** I have setTheme method:

```
setTheme(stylesheetName){
   // what should I write here??
}
```

Comment: hmm the themes need to be separated files? Because maybe you can have a single .scss file with both themes and use a class in the body element to toggle theme1 or theme2. Your .scss file would be like  `body.theme1 { // theme1 css rules} body.theme2 { // theme2 css rules}`

Comment: @sebaferreras  I will go for your solution, can you make an example? I don't understand how I can change the body class based on the clicked div

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="theme1" [ngClass]="theme" (click)="theme = 'theme1'">Apply Theme 1</div>
<div id="theme2" [ngClass]="theme" (click)="theme = 'theme2'">Apply Theme 2</div>
```

I don't know about loading *.css files depending on classes set though.

Comment: ok, If I do like that when I click on a div its class will change but what If I want to change body class when div is clicked? I tried with [body.ngClass] but I got a template error

Comment: In this case my approach won't work. Your question was not too clear about that ;-)